# How do I completely delete my App Engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've decided to go with Google Compute Engine instead of App Engine. 
I want to completely disable the App Engine. 
I've already deployed an empty project (app.yaml + empty index.php) instead of the older one to save on storage space, but the URL (*.appspot.com) is still accessible and it'll create instances when accessed. 
How do I disable that?

Answer (score 10):

If you go to `application settings` on the console then `Disable or Delete Application` you can stop instances spinning up by disabling the application or queue it for actual deletion.

You may need to go to the "original" console as I'm not sure this option is available yet on the new 'cloud' console.

This link might help with getting to that original console if needed:

> https://appengine.google.com/settings?&app_id=s~YOUR_APP_ID

Here's a screenshot of the location of the disable application button on settings page:

[image: the location of the disable application button on settings page]

Comment: I'm getting this: `Server Error
A server error has occurred.` when trying to access application settings, very odd.

Comment: If your app is hosted in the EU, you need to change the `s~` to `e~` ...if that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to shutdown your project and that will queue it for deletion.

To do that, go to **IAM & admin** > **Settings** for that particular project.
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings/project?project=%appengine_id%

Then click on **SHUT DOWN**.

[image]

It will take 30 days for the appengine project to be completely deleted.

Answer (score -2):

For the [Cloud Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) you need to select the App Project that you want to delete. Then you have to go to "Billing & settings". Then click "Delete project" to delete your App project.

Comment: deleting a project deletes all resources, not just App Engine

Answer (score -2):

Use this [console](https://console.developers.google.com) to delete your app.

Click the "Remove" Icon to delete your apps.

You can see all of those deleted apps by clicking "Projects pending deletion".

You will receive an email next day, whose title is "Project Removal Announcement".

The Google Developers Console team will remove your project permanently one week from the time of your request.

Comment: deleting a project deletes all resources, not just App Engine